# Отсутствуют некоторые методы в System.Net.HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Слева - `ConsoleApplication`, справа - `WindowsUniversalAppication`.
Подскажите, что нужно сделать, чтобы справа был такой же набор методов, как слева?

Comment: Ничего, под платформой UWP у вас другой фреймворк, и в нём другие методы.

Comment: А чего конкретно вам не хватает?

Comment: Выбирал .NET Framework 4.6.1 при создании проекта, нашел .NET for WU, но здесь нет нужного метода.
Не хватает GetResponce(). Подскажите, что делать. Приложение должно быть UWA

Comment: Да вроде должно быть. Вот: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/system.net.httpwebrequest.getresponse.aspx

Comment: @VladD У вас неправильная ссылка: раздел UWP, но статья из большого .NET. Присмотритесь к шапке страницы. :)

Comment: @Discord: Хм. Похоже, что правда. После последнего реструктурирования MSDN непонятно, что к чему относится. И где искать аналоги под другие варианты платформы.

Comment: @VladD Хм... Теоретически меню слева можно воспользоваться: Develop > Windows API reference > .NET APIs > .NET for UWP apps > System.Net namespaces for UWP apps > HttpWebRequest. Но всё равно оказываемся на вашей ссылке. Там сверху предупреждение: "Note that .NET for UWP apps does not include all the members of each type. For information about individual types, see the linked topics. The documentation for a type indicates which members are included in .NET for UWP apps." В статье "GetResponse" снизу только ".NET Framework", а вот в "GetResponseAsync" есть "Universal Windows Platform" и прочие.

Comment: @Discord: Хм, так и не нашёл это самое предупреждение. А вот Version Information вроде в порядке.

Comment: @VladD https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/mt185489.aspx

Comment: @Discord: Точно, туда-то я и не заглянул. Запрятали :)

Comment: @VladD Фильтрации членов по версиям фреймворка явно не хватает... По-нормальному должна быть переключалка в "Other versions", но UWP не удостоился такой чести. Да и PCL тоже. Впрочем, я даже не представляю, как в справку все версии PCL впихать. В общем и целом, с зоопарком фреймворков полный мрак. И даже .NET Core проблемы не решает, а только добавляет ещё один пунктик.

Comment: @Discord: Ну, у Майкрософта есть UI-дизайнеры, пусть думают, как лучше представить весь зоопарк. У них же вроде есть [переключалка любимого языка](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.aspx#Anchor_7).

Comment: @VladD Эти дезигнеры уже выпилили галки "inherited" и "protected" из списков членов, поэтому я бы не рассчитывал на прогресс. :( Ну хоть интерфейс упростили...

Comment: @Discord: Ага, мне их не хватает. Хотя если бы они предложили что-то лучшее, чтобы не искать среди миллиона методов, было бы круто. Группировка по смыслу? Это надо везде теги в документации прописывать. В общем, идеальная документация будет не скоро.

Comment: @VladD Надо отметить, что справка у мелкомягких — одна из лучших. Очень сильный контраст при переходе от стиля "по объёмной статье со всеми подробностями на член" к "по статье на класс с двумя строчками описания каждого члена", как принято во многих других местах.

Comment: @Discord: Хм, думаете, это я с жиру бешусь? Вообще-то да, видел недавно документацию по какой-то 3rdparty-библиотеке. Прослезился.

Answer (score 4):

На UWP многие методы существуют только в асинхронном виде. Вместо `GetResponse()` следует использовать `await GetResponseAsync()`.